# How to download packages from a command-line given repository?

Tags: debian, dpkg

It is not about the common download & install thing, what apt (aptitude, etc) does, it is a scripted *download* a package file.

I found the `dget` tool for this task, which works quite well. But, unfortunately, it doesn't have any option to specify a different repository URL as it is given in the `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Is it somehow possible? Actually, a `dget`-like functionality would be the best, *but* where I can also specify the repo URL.

---

P.s. thank you very much the scripts, but I would like to prefer a debian tool for this *very* *simple* task. It will be part of a buildscript, for external usage, and *any* unneeded complexity has intolerable collateral costs. It must be done by a debian tool.

P.s.2. Finally I solved this with updating the system-wide repos, and downloading the packages with `dget`. Thank you very much the scripts!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "`dget` doesn't have any option to specify a different repository URL"? It takes the URL on the command line... Or does `apt-get --download-only install` provide what you're after?

Comment: @StephenKitt The URL option of the dget specifies a package URL, and not a repository URL. I want to download packages from a remote repo 1) automatized 2) without modifying my /etc/apt/sources.list . But, I don't know the exact URLs of the packages, I know only their name and the exact URL of their repo. | apt-get would also download dependencies, and has a complex configuration. I don't need these.

Comment: Could you translate “the script-solutions also get now an up, but not a pipe” into English? What does this question have to do with pipes?

Comment: Are you going to run this on a Debian (or Debian-based) system, or are you looking for something that can be deployed on any unix-like system?

Comment: @Gilles Well, "pipe" has different meanings in Unix and in SE context :-) I "translated".

Comment: @Gilles Debian-based system. It will be deployed anywhere, where docker runs. Meanwhile I solved the problem in such a way, that no package download is needed, but it is only a temporary solution. On the longterm, it won't go. Of course there is a secondary reason: I can't imagine that there is no tool for such a simple task, so I will make a bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running a reasonably recent version of Debian or other distribution using apt, you can use `apt-get` for this. Put the following settings in a file called `apt-get.conf` to make it not use

```
Dir::Etc::main ".";
Dir::Etc::Parts "./apt.conf.d";
Dir::Etc::sourcelist "./sources.list";
Dir::Etc::sourceparts "./sources.list.d";
Dir::State "./apt-tmp";
Dir::State::status "./apt-tmp/status";
Dir::Cache "./apt-tmp";
```

Prepare some necessary files:

```
mkdir -p apt-tmp/lists/partial
touch apt-tmp/status
apt-get -c apt.conf update >/dev/null
```

Then you can download packages to the current directory with

```
apt-get -c apt.conf download $packages
```

With old versions of `apt-get` that lack the `download` command, you can use

```
apt-get -c apt.conf install -d $packages
```

to download packages and their dependencies into `apt-tmp/archives`.

Answer (score 10):

All the tools I can find use the local `apt` information (and hence repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` etc., as defined the last time `apt-get update` was run). It's not too difficult to interpret the [repository format](https://wiki.debian.org/RepositoryFormat) though.

Save

```
#!/bin/sh
# Downloads a package from a repository
# dlpkg repo distro suite arch package

for arch in all "${4}"; do
    curl "${1}/dists/${2}/${3}/binary-${arch}/Packages.xz" | xz -d | "$(dirname $0)/pkgfilename" -v "PACKAGE=${5}" | while read filename; do
        curl -O "${1}/${filename}"
    done
done
```

as `dlpkg`, and

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/Package:/ {
    package = $2
}

package == PACKAGE && /Filename:/ {
    print $2
}
```

as `pkgfilename`, make them executable, and you can then download a package by running

```
./dlpkg <repository URL> <distribution> <suite> <architecture> <package>
```

for example

```
./dlpkg http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian unstable main amd64 libc6
```

If you need to handle repositories whose `Packages` files aren't in canonical order (`Package` before `Filename`), you can use the following AWK script instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    filename = ""
}

/^$/ {
    filename = ""
    stanza = 0
}

/Package:/ {
    if ($2 == PACKAGE) {
        stanza = 1
        if (filename != "") {
            print filename
            stanza = 0
        }
    }
}

/Filename:/ {
    filename = $2
    if (stanza == 1) {
        print filename
        filename = ""
    }
}
```

There's no error-handling, that's left as an exercise for the reader. There's no signature verification either...

Comment: Finally I solved with dget, although I wasn't happy to modify the system-wide repos. But, thank you very much script!

Comment: @peterh could you post the solution you *actually* used as an answer, instead of leaving everyone guessing? Thanks!

Comment: This script doesn't work. I guess there should be some program called with `"$(dirname $0...`

Comment: @Adam you need to save the two files, `dlpkg` and `pkgfilename`, in the same directory. The `dirname $0` construct allows `dlpkg` to find `pkgfilename`.

Answer (score 2):

Well maybe this script is a solution for your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

U="$1"
FILE="$2"

[[ -z "$U" ]] && echo -e "Usage: $0 repo-url [file to download]\nwithout give \"file to download\" this script will list the files inside the repo\n";

for i in $(curl -l "$U" 2>/dev/null|grep -i 'href='|sed -e 's/.*href=//g' -e 's/>.*//g' -e 's/"//g'|grep -v '/$'|grep "$FILE")
do
 if [[ -z "$FILE" ]]
 then
  echo "FILE: $i"
 else
  echo "Download file: $i"
  curl -q "${U}/${i}" --output "$i" 2>/dev/null
  ls -la "$i"
 fi
done
```

Comment: I am looking for mainly a "clean" debian thing, my solution will be part of build scripts where unneeded complexity has high collateral costs. But, if there is no better solution for that, it will be acceptable. (Again: I don't need to install the package, and particularly not its repositories, I only want to download it. Thus, the apt install thing is not really needed at the end of your script, but it will be easy to change to dget.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you're trying to achieve is in line with the idea of having repos as such. The idea being, you'd have to add the repo to the repolist, and then install from it, etc.

It is possible to download a package manually (I do that quite often with RPM packages for Fedora), and install a package manually with the regular tools (in my case `dnf`).

I usually use the URL from `/etc/yum.repos.d/<repo>.repo` and then just browse with a browser, and download with `wget`. It should be analogous with DEB packages.

So,

1. Download package manually with a browser or `wget`
2. Install with your package management client from cli.

If the repo is directly available online (which I don't see why not), `dnf` understands when it is given a URL to an RPM package. I'm sure the equivalent Debian tool will do the same. So you'll save yourself downloading the package with a browser or with `wget`.

As I understand it, you'r only interested in just *downloading* the packages. So in that case, I think using plain `wget` is the best way to go, etc.

Comment: Repos are static file repositories with static file indices, whose primary function is to find the package URL based on its name (and other metadata, like version, distrib codename, etc). This is exactly what I wish. What I do with the downloaded packages, isn't a business of the repo. It only provides packages. Writing a script for that seems impractical, while the required functionality is already available in many debian tools, although it could be acceptable if there is no better.

Comment: @peterh In that case I'd suggest you'd simply get the rest of the information from `uname` and assemble the information. As I understand it, you want to provide a repo baseurl manually via cli an the client tool would search for a package inside of it? if so, I don't think there's an `apt-cache` search tool for cli repos available.

Comment: `apt-cache` uses the systemwide apt package cache, and I've already explained why I won't use the systemwide apt cache. It would be like shooting with cannon to a fly.

Comment: uname  can say at most the architecture. The exact URL can be found only in the package index of the repository. My main prolem with the debian that finding the correct tool for a simple task is often harder as reimplement it with a little bit of scripting.